# Android/Java substitute for NSNotificationCenter that does not need a Context reference

Tags: android, ios, events, nsnotificationcenter

So far I have worked on several iOS projects and currently I am porting one of these apps to my first android app.

The data model of iOS Version uses `NSNotificationCenter` to broadcast status messages that are used notify the view classes about updates. This works very well and is comfortable since the views do not need to know/see all model classes but only the update messages.

I am trying to do the same on Android. Of course there is no `NSNotificationCenter` here but I found the [`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to be almost the same. Almost the same, but not exactly the same: The `getInstance(...)` methods need a reference to the `Context` (e.g. an `Activity`). This is a problem because the model classes don't know any `Activity` ore `Context`.

All information I found say, that if a model class has to know an `Activity` it should get a reference to it, e.g. within the constructor. But it would be a realy "ugly" solution to pass down such a reference through the chain of model classes just to be able to post notifications.

Is there any other solution to use `NSNotificationCenter` in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this great library for event handling in Android apps. It should be what you're looking for.

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus